# ChefDk issue with knife command

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I've cloned my Chef setup on my MacBook. The only difference is I'm using the latest version of `ChefDk`. All the keys, knife.rb, etc. are installed, but I get a one line error message when trying to use knife...

> Need modules 'fog' and 'chef/knife/bootstrap' - install it first!

Does anyone have a clue what the message is asking me to rectify? The embedded `fog` gem is installed. I would assume the installation would install everything necessary, and I've never had this issue before.

Comment: did you try to use chef as a rubygem under bundler context?

Comment: No. I did get a little further by creating config.rb as a symlink to my knife.rb. This seems to be an issue with reading my personal pem file.

Comment: there was indeed changes in the configuration files naming and and locations, which depends on which version of chef you are using. yet, i upgraded my chef gem without any breakage... but i was using bundler. if you solved the issue, could you please post an answer? :)